# Is there a way to compare two song(Audio/Video) file?

Tags: android

How to compare two song stored in two files and see, if they are same or not?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're not just looking to compare the files, but the actual music encoded within, you need to come up with a way to generate a fingerprint.  For music, check out the [MusicBrainz.org](http://musicbrainz.org) - they have open source libraries for getting from a song to it's metadata.  Not sure if such a project exists for video though.

Comment: Thanks for the information and i will go through that information and wait for more answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use a open source Library for it. like musicg . Only down side is using that library is you can only compare wave files.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible by using the [Follow this article](http://www.simplecodestuffs.com/compare-two-files-by-content-in-java/)

1. Download the Apache Commons IO 2.5 API from [Here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io/2.4)
2. Add jar file in tools which you are following. (netbeans,eclips,android studio)
3. Import libarary "import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils";

you then have to use only this function.

```
File file1 = new File("1st_File_Path");
File file2 = new File("2nd_File_Path");
boolean compareResult = FileUtils.contentEquals(file1, file2);
System.out.println("Are the files are same? " + compareResult);
```

must remember to vote :)

Comment: Sorry for this answer i think! you want to find two duplicate music files!
but you want to find two music file by streaming....  :(